# Saving Records Using Java

Tags: java, mysql, date

I am saving date logs every time a user logs in. Date logs will save a date in the record, but what I want is for there to be no duplicates. It will check if the record is already existing, and if yes
it will not save the date. If the record does not yet exist it will save the date.

Here is my code:

```
 SimpleDateFormat dnow2 = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMMM dd, yyyy");

 ResultSet ds = MyDB.rsFetch("SELECT * FROM `date-logs` WHERE `Date` = '"+dnow.format(new java.util.Date())+"'");

 try {
   ds.next() ; 

   if (ds.getMetaData().getColumnCount() == 0) {
     MyDB.exSQL(  "INSERT INTO `date-logs` (`Date Code`, `Date`) " 
                + "VALUES ('"+dnow.format(new java.util.Date())+ "',"
                + "'"+dnow2.format(new java.util.Date())+"')");   
   }
 } catch (SQLException ex) {
   Logger.getLogger(FrmLogIn.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
 }
```

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: if there existing record to the database it will not save anymore if. new record it will save. when i run this nothing happens can you help me

Comment: Have you checked if your SELECT query is working properly, i.e if it is actually returning any result. Looks like you are formatting your date as "MMMMM dd, yyyy" which evaluates to 'February 21, 2013'. Can you check if the query SELECT * FROM `date-logs` WHERE `Date` = 'February 21, 2013' is retriving any result.

Comment: yes its working properly

Comment: all I just want to happen if the record is already existing it will not save anymore if, if new record it will save

Answer (score 1):

Finally I got it !!!

```
 SimpleDateFormat dnow2 = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMMM dd, yyyy");

    ResultSet ds = MyDB.rsFetch("SELECT * FROM `date-logs` WHERE `Date Code` = '"+dnow.format(new java.util.Date())+"'");


  int resultsCounter = 0;  
    try {
        while(ds.next())  
        {  
        //procedure when results were returned  
        resultsCounter++;  
        }

        if (resultsCounter ==0)  
        {  

      MyDB.exSQL("INSERT INTO `date-logs` (`Date Code`, `Date`) VALUES ('"+dnow.format(new java.util.Date())+ "',"
                     + "'"+dnow2.format(new java.util.Date())+"')");
        }  
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(FrmLogIn.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know which database abstraction stuff you're using, but you should update it to use [prepared statements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html).

Next, you should use MySQL specific query, like:

```
insert into date logs ... on duplicate key ignore
```

make sure that Date is primary key. This kind of query will ignore inserts if the key already exists in the database.

Comment: if I make that primary then when another user will login it will cause an error

Comment: According to your example, you are not storing any user-specific information in logs table, so it doesn't matter. If it does - you may use compound primary key on username and date columns.

Comment: MyDB.exSQL(  "INSERT INTO `date-logs` (`Date Code`, `Date`) " 
                + "VALUES ('"+dnow.format(new java.util.Date())+ "',"
                + "'"+dnow2.format(new java.util.Date())+"')");

Comment: date-log is in the other table so when one user will log in... this code will run

Answer (score 0):

What you should be doing is to add another foreign key for user (make it primary as well) to the `date-logs` table. Even if you insert the same data twice it will ignore the query since the primary key already exists in the database.